# Definition of first countable topogical space.

Tags: general-topology

Ok, I am a bit confused.

Does first countability mean that for every element $x$ in the space, there is a collection of open sets and each of those open sets are countable containing $x$ and for every open neighborhood of $x$, one of those countable open set is contained in.

OR

For every element $x$ in the space, there is a collection of open sets, where the number of sets in this collection is countably many, that contains $x$ and for every neighborhood of $x$, one of those open sets (not necessarily countable) is contained in?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: The second is correct. For every $x$ there is a countable collection $\mathcal V$ of open sets that contain $x$ as element, and such that for every open set $O$ that contains $x$ as element there is a $V\in\mathcal V$ with $x\in V\subseteq O$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is wrong. Even in the real line open sets are all uncountable so the condition there is not satisfied. The second definition is correct.

Answer (score 1):

It's more the second one, put formally: for each $x \in X$ there is an at most countable collection $U_n(x), n \in \mathbb{N}$ of open neighbourhoods of $x$ such that for each open set $O$ that contains $x$ there is an $n$ such that $U_n(x) \subseteq O$.

FYI as a curiosity, if the $U_n(x)$ are just required to be open (but not always a neighbourhood of $x$) but do satify the final condition, these are not called local bases, but local pseudo-bases, and $X$ is not called first countable but of countable pseudocharacter.